# Error deploying to a jbossfuse 6.3 server with Developer profile

Tags: java, maven-plugin, acl, jbossfuse, fabric8

I've got the following error trying to deploy an app to a remote JbossFuse 6.3 server with a different profile from "admin"

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:1.2.0.redhat-630187:deploy (default-cli) on project sap-connect-test: Error executing: java.lang.Exception : Operation deployProjectJson forbidden for MBean io.fabric8:type=ProjectDeployer -> [Help 1]
```

the user I'm trying to use:

```
developers  {CRYPT}XXXX{CRYPT},viewer,Deployer,Auditor
```

I don't want to give "admin" access to developers to avoid errors messing with the containers and server configurations, they have to be able only to deploy apps, stop and start them, see logs, etc.

If I use the user "admin" the deploy is succesfully executed.

Comment: I managed to make the deployment assigning the ADMIN role